# Vue 3 Pina trying to test a pina store that has a dependency on another store

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs, vuejs3

I basically have a store that depends on another store and I don't see a way to only mock the dependent store.
example pseudo code vue 3 ish:

```
// the store I want to mock
export const useStore1 = defineStore({
    id: 'store1',
    state: (): State => ({
  
        someName:'blarg', // I know this is static but lets pretend it can change.
    }),
    // getter I want to mock
    getters: {
        name: (state) => state.someName,
    }
}

// store I want to test

export const useStoreTwo = defineStore({
    id: 'store2',
    state: (): State => ({
  
       someValue:'bar'
    }),
    getters: {
        value: (state) => {
        const store1 = useStore1() // dependency here
        return `${store1.name} state.someValue`
        },
    }
}


test
it('should return something' () => {
      //**** 
         someplace I would mock useStateOne and have it return
         a stub store with the getter name that returns 'foo'
      ***//
      const store2 = useStoreTwo();
      expect(store2.value).toBe('foo bar');
})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is helpful to you.

https://pinia.vuejs.org/cookbook/testing.html#mocking-getters

> By default, any getter will be computed like regular usage **but you can
> manually force a value by setting the getter to anything you want**

```
import { createTestingPinia } from '@pinia/testing';

const pinia = createTestingPinia()
    
it('should return something' () => {
   const store1 = useStore1(pinia);
   store1.name = "foobar";
    
   const store2 = useStoreTwo();
   expect(store2.value).toBe('foobar');
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this issue by mocking the imported `useStore` like this:

```
import { useXyStore } from './xyStore ';
jest.mock('./xyStore '); // mock the dependancy store

describe('tests', () => {
    const xyStoreMock = {
         anyStoreAction: jest.fn(),
    };
    const useXyStoreMock = jest.mocked(useXyStore);
    
    beforeEach(() => {
         useXyStoreMock.mockReturnValue(xyStoreMock);
         setActivePinia(createPinia()); // use the acutal pinia store for store that you are testing
    });
});
```

This is also achivable with Vitest. Just use the equivalent `vi` functions.